# Time Series Moving-average model

Tags: r, time-series, arima

There is a way, in R, to make a model with MA coefficients like that:

> Xt = µ + εt + θεt-3 + θεt-8

I searched but I couldn't find a way.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have data for which you are trying to find the best coefficients for this model? Or are you looking to simulate observations from known coefficients?

Comment: I have the data. I trying to find the best model but on r  only know arima function